# AttributeError: StringVar instance has no attribute 'endswith' while trying to call from a Tkinter button

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, glob

I would like to create a GUI that receives two paths (a directory full of .txt documents and the destination of a new .csv file created from the files of the previously mentioned folder).

[image]

I am having trouble calling the function `munge()`:

```
action = tk.Button(win, text="To .csv",command=munge(input_directory,output_directory))
```

Nevertheless, this exception raised:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/user/PycharmProjects/script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/script.py", line 82, in <module>
    action = tk.Button(win, text="To .csv", command=munge(input_directory,output_directory))
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/script.py", line 39, in munge
    test = tuple(retrive(directory))
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/script.py", line 31, in retrive
    for filename in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, '*.txt'))):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 70, in join
    elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: StringVar instance has no attribute 'endswith'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I correctly call the aforementioned function with the help of the Button widget?. I tried to set the name of the variable as indicated here [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928937/issue-with-stringvar-in-python-program), but it did not worked.

**update**

Then from an answer of this question, I tried the following:

```
action = tk.Button(win, text="To .csv", command=lambda:munge(input_directory,output_directory))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, it worked with: action = `tk.Button(win, text="To .csv", command=lambda:munge(input_directory.get(),output_directory.get()))`. However, from Bryan Oakley answer I belive that this is not the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the error message, you seem to be trying to call the `endswith` method of a `StringVar` object. If you look at the documentation for such an object you'll see there's no such method. That is why you get the error that you do.

Assuming that `path` is an instance of a `StringVar`, you must call the `get` method in order to have the string stored by the object:

```
path_string = path.get()
if path_string == "" or path_string.endswith('/'):
    ...
```

Comment: Wow... it worked with: `action = tk.Button(win, text="To .csv", command=lambda:munge(input_directory.get(),output_directory.get()))`. However, I would like to know if this is the correct way to do this, do the previous solution is a pythonic way to solve this issue?.

Comment: @john_doe: The better way is for `command=some_function`, and then have `some_function` get the variables. In my opinion, `lambda` should only be used if it's strictly necessary.

Comment: Could you provide an example?. Just to give you the bounty?

Answer (score 1):

You want to call the `.get()` method on the StringVar to get the string it contains otherwise it's just the StringVar instance.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider reading a bit on callback functions in Tkinter, here is a useful link in order to do so http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm:

> For simple cases like this, you can use a lambda expression as a link
>   between Tkinter and the callback function:

```
def callback(number):
    print "button", number

Button(text="one",   command=lambda: callback(1))
```

your function is being executed as soon as your Button widget loads, you want to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried your approach: `action = tk.Button(win, text="To .csv", command=lambda:munge(input_directory,output_directory))`. However, I still get the same error, any idea of why is happening this issue?.

Comment: the error you are getting is related to your function, the lambda will help you execute your function when you actually click on the button rather than onload. "How can I correctly call the aforementioned function with the help of the button"

Comment: The thing is that I have been using this functions for an argparse menu, and they actually worked perfect. On the other hand, this issue started when I tryed to start using Tkinter's `StringVar()`object. What should I do?

Comment: While you've pointed out a bug in the code, it's not the bug that's being asked about.