# Creating multiple empty string variables using StringVar() from Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to create a large number of variables that take string input and that initially will be **empty** (pending user input).

Previously I've created the variables one at the time, eg

`customer_id = StringVar() 
 customer_age = StringVar()`

etc but this looks messy with a large number of variables.

I've looked at the answer in [Issue with 'StringVar' in Python Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928937/issue-with-stringvar-in-python-program) but I can't figure out how to use StringVar() with a for loop and a list.

I'm using Python 3.7.4, Windows 10.

```
# ATTEMPT 
from tkinter import * 
varlist = ['customer_id', 'customer_age', 'customer_phone']               
for var in varlist:
    Tk()
    var = StringVar()

# ERROR MESSAGE WHEN CHECKING VARIABLES
type(customer_id) 

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-9625f8af3cc2> in <module>
----> 1 type(customer_id)

NameError: name 'customer_id' is not defined
```

Thanks!

Comment: Part of the problem is that you're creating multiple root windows. You need to remove `Tk()` from the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dict.

```
varlist = {var: StringVar() for var in ["customer_id", "customer_age", "customer_phone"]}
```

Now use `varlist["customer_id"]` where you would have used the variable `customer_id`.

Comment: When I run it I get:   File "<ipython-input-6-35d53a43f178>", line 7
    varlist = {var: StringVar() for var in "customer_id", "customer_age", "customer_phone"}
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Fixed; I forgot to wrap the elements in a list literal.